# Registros se duplican en proyecto laravel 5.5 subido a servidor

Tags: php, laravel

Holo tengo un proyecto que en local va bien, pero por alguna razón al subirlo funciona pero me están pasando cosas extrañas como que al ingresar un  "artista" (modulo en mi sistema) crea dos registros con id deferente y todo pero ejemplo si intento borrar uno de los dos desde la aplicación me los borra ambos, esto mismo me ocurre en otras partes de la aplicación, me parece extremadamente raro ya que en local está perfecto, ¿qué puede estar variando en todo esto, que hace que suceda este problema?

Agrego código de mi controlador para facturas es uno de los que me está dando problemas:

public function store(FacturaRequest $request)
    {
            // return response()->json([ 'mensaje' => $request->all() ]);

```
    $concepto = $request->input('concepto');
    $descripcion = $request->input('descripcion');
    $cant_horas = $request->input('cant_horas');
    $precio = $request->input('precio');
    $total_horas = $request->input('total_horas');
    $impuesto = $request->input('impuesto');
    $porcentaje = $request->input('porcentaje');
    $total_impuesto = $request->input('total_impuesto');

         $count = DB::table('facturas_genericas')->count();

    $numero_factura = '0000'.$count;
        $factura = Factura::create([
                        'numero_factura'=> $numero_factura, 
                        'fecha_factura'=>date('Y-m-d'),
                        'des_factura'=>$request->input('des_factura'),
                        'estado'=> 'Creada',
                        'total'=> $request->input('total_general'),
                        'beneficiario'=>$request->input('beneficiario'),
                        'cif'=>$request->input('cif'),
                        'email'=>$request->input('email'),

                ]);

    // se ingresan los conceptos
    foreach ($cant_horas as $key => $cant_hora) {

        $detalleFactura = detalleFacGenerica::create([
                            'concepto'=> $concepto[$key], 
                            'descripcion'=> $descripcion[$key],
                            'cant_horas'=> $cant_horas[$key],
                            'precio'=> $precio[$key],
                            'total_horas'=> $total_horas[$key],
                            'factura_id'=> $factura->id
                    ]);

    }

    // se ingresan los impuestos
    foreach ($impuesto as $key => $impuesto_value) {

        $detalleFactura = Impuesto::create([
                            'impuesto'=> $impuesto[$key], 
                            'porcentaje'=> $porcentaje[$key],
                            'total_impuesto'=> $total_impuesto[$key],
                            'factura_id'=> $factura->id
                    ]);

    }

    return response()->json([
            "mensaje" => "Factura Creada"
        ]);

}
```

Paso los datos por ajax y los recibo arriba de ese modo, porque todos son arrays generados de una serie de filas dinámicas, hago uso de uno de esos arrays para recorrer los demás y registrar

Comment: Si código nadie te va a contestar

Comment: Buenas Paula, así es difícil saber tu problema si puedes ser mas especifica  te facilitaríamos mejor ayuda gracias.

Comment: gracias acabo de editar la pregunta, quiero acolarar que esto no es algo recurrente, es decir el duplicado surge de vez en cuando no es todo el tiempo por eso también mi interrogante porque es algo ocasional

Comment: Alguien hace un doble click en un boton?

Comment: Intenta deshabilitar el doble click a tu boton submit, o colocar un cargando...

Comment: si, efectivamente esto soluciono mi problema gracias :)